# Rewrite-dynamic URL .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to re-write the dynamically generated URL. But the rules i have written is not affecting the **URL** even a single bit.

The URL currently shows up like: ***http://ukfurniturespecialist.co.uk/county.php?c=Oxfordshire&%20t=Faringdon***

And i would like it to look like: http://ukfurniturespecialist.co.uk/county-c-Oxfordshire-t-Faringdon.html

This is what i have tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule county-c-(.*)-%20t-(.*)\.html$ county.php?c=$1&%20t=$2
```

Any help is much appreciated,Thanks.

Comment: Why is that `%20` in there? If you simply to: `^county-c-(.*)$` does it go to `county.php`?

Comment: I think `%xx` codes are transformed to their actual character, but I am not 100% sure. You would need to match `\ ` instead in that case.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: No it doesn't :(

Comment: What if you simplify to `^(.*)$`? (ie. match everything)

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: I have changed it to   RewriteRule county^(.*).html$ county.php?c=$1&\%20t=$2 [L,QSA,NE]     but still showing the same old url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your URL following rule should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+county\.php\?c=([^&]*)&.*?t=([^&\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ county-c-%1-t-%2.html? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^county-c-([^-]+)-t-([^.]+)\.html$ county.php?c=$1&\%20t=$2 [L,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhav its nice to have someone anubhavi like you here ;). But i have tried what you have suggested and still getting the same old url.

Comment: ok check my updated code and place it in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`

Comment: I have placed the updated code and placed it in the root. This is really weird i'm still getting the same old url. Am i missing something that needs to be checked, i mean i have tried whatever has been suggested by each of the stackoverflower here in this post and the result is always the same old url.

Answer (score 1):

%20 represents a space character in url. when writing rewrite rule the url is already decoded and handled using  "\ " instead of %20

For your URL the rewrite rule should be

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule county-c-(.*)-\ t-(.*)\.html$ county.php?c=$1&\ t=$2
```

I dont think you need to put space character in your url. If you remove the %20 from your URL the rewrite rule should be

```
RewriteRule county-c-(.*)-t-(.*)\.html$ county.php?c=$1&t=$2
```

Comment: Thanks for posting in here ZubaiR. This is really weird i'm still getting the same old url. Am i missing something that needs to be checked, i mean i have tried whatever has been suggested by each of the stackoverflower here in this post and the result is always the same old url.

Comment: after placing this code your both url should work. i.e. from your browser you will be able to access both http://ukfurniturespecialist.co.uk/county-c-Oxfordshire-t-Faringdon.html and http://ukfurniturespecialist.co.uk/county.php?c=Oxfordshire&%20t=Faringdon

Comment: Both the urls are working fine. That's not the problem is. The problem is the url gets displayed in the browser implicitly is the second one.

Comment: I just visited the page and when i access http://ukfurniturespecialist.co.uk/county-c-Oxfordshire-t-Faringdon.html directly I see exactly this link in URL, not the php one. Are you visiting this link from another page ? May be the link to this page is set to the php link instead of html ?

Comment: Yes that's because i have added the updated code suggested by @anubhav. Anyways thanks for putting in effort, upvoted you for this. :)